# XCode Custom Activity Indicator - Hide after UIWebView Loads (webViewDidFinishLoad)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview, activity-indicator

I'm using the code found here http://blog.blackwhale.at/?p=336 to create a custom `activityIndicator` in the current version of xCode. This code uses a series of `.png` images in an array and then displays them at the set interval to create an animated loading image that you can then place on the screen (and assuming you can somehow remove it) whenever you want.

In my main ViewController.m file I have the following code in my `viewDidLoad` section :

```
/* --- START CUSTOM ACTIVITY INDICATOR */
    //Create the first status image and the indicator view
    UIImage *statusImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity1.png"];
    UIImageView *activityImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] 
                                      initWithImage:statusImage];
    
    
    //Add more images which will be used for the animation
    activityImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity1.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity2.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity3.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity4.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity5.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity6.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity7.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity8.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity9.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity10.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity11.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity12.png"],
                                         nil];
    
    
    //Set the duration of the animation (play with it
    //until it looks nice for you)
    activityImageView.animationDuration = 0.6;
    
    
    //Position the activity image view somewhere in 
    //the middle of your current view
    activityImageView.frame = CGRectMake(
                                         self.view.frame.size.width/2
                                         -statusImage.size.width/2, 
                                         self.view.frame.size.height/1.2
                                         -statusImage.size.height/1.2, 
                                         statusImage.size.width, 
                                         statusImage.size.height);
    
    //Start the animation
    [activityImageView startAnimating];
    
    
    //Add your custom activity indicator to your current view
    [self.view addSubview:activityImageView];

    
   /*  --- END CUSTOM ACTIVITY INDICATOR */
```

I would like to CLEAR/DELETE/HIDE the `activityImageView` element, as I only want it to show when the app first launches until the `UIWebView` finishes loading.

I would like to call this and have the gif appear while `webViewDidStartLoad` and then clear when `webViewDidFinishLoad`.  Someone help??

Comment: Have you tried just removing activityImageView from your current view after the animation is done? Or better yet, changing the visibility? Or maybe im not understanding what is keeping you from calling it in the two functions you mentioned, perhaps you could clarify the problem youre running into?

Comment: Could you PLEASE tell me how to do that? :) Like what code and where to put it? I catch on pretty quickly. The problem (that I think I'm having but honestly I don't really know) is that the `activityImageView` is not accessible outside of the `viewDidLoad` section...?

Comment: Ah okay, I know what you need to do, I'll post it in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the reason that you cannot access activityImageView is because its declared in your viewDidLoad function. Add it as a property to your ViewController class and you should be able to do what you want. Make sure that you remove the declaration of activityImageView from viewDidLoad, and just initialize it there.

Also, where is your webview that you want to show the activity indicator? Does it have a separate view controller or is it included in your main view controller? It sounds like your scope for activityImageView is incorrect, though without knowing how you have everything set up its a little hard for me to tell you where to put it.

After you use your activity indicator in these two places, do you plan on using it again during the applications run time, or will it only ever be visible if you reload the application? Depending on the answer to that you will either want to just hide it, or remove it from you main view.

UIImageView.hidden is what controls visibility.

EDIT, Code as requested:

```
ViewController.h

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIWebView *_webView;
}

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *webView;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *activityImageView;

ViewController.m

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize activityImageView;
@synthesize webView = _webView;

-(void)viewDidLoad {

    //all your previous stuff with the change that you just alloc activityImageView instead of declare it
    activityImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:statusImage];
    //The above is the initialization, below is where your old code should go
}
```

Comment: Can you give me some sample code? :) Like how would I initialize it there (in your first paragraph)

Comment: Whats the structure of you application? Where is your webView? Is your main view the webView, or is the webView part of the main view?

Comment: In my original code I start the animation and then populate it into the view with `[activityImageView startAnimating];` and `[self.view addSubview:activityImageView];`. How do I remove it when I want it to disappear?

Comment: When you finish your loading you want to do [self.activityImageView removeFromSuperview] to remove the activity indicator.

Answer (score 2):

You should go like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Create the first status image and the indicator view
    UIImage *statusImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity1.png"];
    UIImageView *activityImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] 
                                  initWithImage:statusImage];


    //Add more images which will be used for the animation
    activityImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity1.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity2.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity3.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity4.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity5.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity6.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity7.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity8.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity9.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity10.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity11.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity12.png"],
                                     nil];


    //Set the duration of the animation (play with it
    //until it looks nice for you)
    activityImageView.animationDuration = 0.6;


    //Position the activity image view somewhere in 
    //the middle of your current view
    activityImageView.frame = CGRectMake(
                                     self.view.frame.size.width/2
                                     -statusImage.size.width/2, 
                                     self.view.frame.size.height/1.2
                                     -statusImage.size.height/1.2, 
                                     statusImage.size.width, 
                                     statusImage.size.height);

    //Start the animation
    [activityImageView startAnimating];


    //Add your custom activity indicator to your current view
    [self.view addSubview:activityImageView];

    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0)
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(loading)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];

}

- (void)loading {

    if (!self.webView.loading) {
        [activityImageView stopAnimating];
        activityImageView.hidden = 1;
    } else {
        [activityImageView startAnimating];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your activityImageView as a property in your header file and configure it in your `viewDidLoad:` method

You should add your activityImageView in UIWebViewDelegate method

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

And then `stopAnimating` and `removeFromSuperview` in the UIWebViewDelegate methods

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
```

You should read [UIImageView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the [UIWebViewDelegate protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

UPDATE

In your header:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *activityImageView;
```

In your implementation

```
@synthesize activityImageView;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
  activityImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] 
                                      initWithImage:statusImage];


    //Add more images which will be used for the animation
    activityImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity1.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity2.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity3.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity4.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity5.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity6.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity7.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity8.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity9.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity10.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity11.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity12.png"],
                                         nil];


    //Set the duration of the animation (play with it
    //until it looks nice for you)
    activityImageView.animationDuration = 0.6;


    //Position the activity image view somewhere in 
    //the middle of your current view
    activityImageView.frame = CGRectMake(
                                         self.view.frame.size.width/2
                                         -statusImage.size.width/2, 
                                         self.view.frame.size.height/1.2
                                         -statusImage.size.height/1.2, 
                                         statusImage.size.width, 
                                         statusImage.size.height);
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
[self.activityImageView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:activityImageView];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
[activityImageView stopAnimating];
[activityImageView removeFromSuperview];
}
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
[activityImageView stopAnimating];
[activityImageView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: How do I configure it in my viewDidLoad method? and how do I add my activityImageView in UIWebViewDelegate method? Could you update your code? I'd be SOOO appreciative :)